# Copy value for member variable from enclosing space into struct

Tags: c++, constructor

Consider the following lines of code:

```
template <typename B>
float cannot_change(float second) {
    B b(second);
    return b();
}

int main() {
    static float global = 10;
    struct C {
        float first_ = global;
        float second_;
        C(float second) : second_(second) {}
        float operator()() { return first_ * second_; }
    };
    std::cout << cannot_change<C>(20) << std::endl;
}
```

The function `cannot_change` constructs a template argument `B` with one parameter. The function is fixed and cannot be changed but I know its source code. Suppose I want to pass a struct that takes two member functions (`C`) in this example. I have created the struct `C` which uses the static variable `global`.

I have a few questions:

- Is it legitimate to write the struct `C` as I did or should I refrain from doing this? It seems strange, but I would like to use an element of type `B` inside `cannot_change` with two member variables.
- If this is legitimate, is there another way to set the variable `first_` for `C` than I did? I prefer to copy the variable. Removing the `static` keywords leads to compile errors.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible w/o introducing global variable (or static in your case).

Comment: What does "legitimate" mean to you? In absence of a suspected compiler bug, if C++ code compiled then, by definition, it's "legitimate". Why do you suspect you might need to "refrain" from doing this? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Well you can try some creepy stuff, like encoding a pointer value into float and then decode it inside `operator()`, but it will only work if strict aliasing is disabled (and if `float` is wide enough)

Comment: What you are trying to do looks like a capture, so a lambda function might be more appropriate. You'd capture the `first` by value and have the lambda code use it with its parameter.

Comment: On a side note, "global" is a strange name for a local variable. (You need the `static` precisely because it is local, but you can use `constexpr` as well.)

Comment: `B` can have as many members as you like, it can also have constructors with any number of parameters, it just must have one that can be called with 1 argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is a best done with a lambda capture, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    const float local = 10;
    auto f = [local](float second) { return local * second; };

    std::cout << f(20) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can make a template lambda too if you need to deal with some class's members (so instead of `float second`, you would write `const B & b` and use `b.member` in the function's body), like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    const float local = 10;
    struct Something {
       float member1;
       float member2;
    };
    auto f = [local]<typename B>(const B & b) { return local * b.member1 + b.member2; };

    std::cout << f(Something{3, 14}) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Gd37YqKT9)

If you really need to call `cannot_change` with this interface, then you can workaround it, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


// You can't change this, so you can't use a lambda directly here
template <typename B>
float cannot_change(float second) {
    B b(second);
    return b();
}

// Here's the function signature of the lambda (and the functor B)
typedef float (*func_type)(float);

namespace details
{
    // Here the idea is to capture the lambda in a std::function static instance. 
    // We are not capturing the context of the lambda but the lambda instance itself
    template <typename T>
    struct CaptureLambda {
        // That's the function pointer that'll be used by the Adapter class. 
        // It's instantiated by the compiler on line 35
        static float adapter(float f) {
            // Actually call the std::function => lambda with the "second" parameter of B
            return get()(f);
        };
        // Usual trick to create a static instance of something in a template class
        static std::function<float(float)> & get() { static std::function<float(float)> t; return t; }
        // Set the std::function instance to point to the lambda
        static void set(T & t) { CaptureLambda::get() = t; }
    };
}

// This is the adapted class that's following the expectation of 
// "cannot_change" function. It has compile-time captured the CaptureLambda::adapter function
template <func_type func>
struct Adapter
{
    // Store the result of the computation of the lambda
    float result;
    // Simplest solution. You could also compute the result in the () operator, but you'd need to store the parameter
    Adapter(float param) : result(func(param)) {}
    float operator ()() const { return result; }
};
int main()
{
    // Here's a local you want to capture
    const float local = 10;
    // Here's the lambda that's doing the work
    auto f = [local](float second) -> float { return local * second; };
    
    // Because I'm lazy typing long types, create an alias.
    typedef details::CaptureLambda<decltype(f)> CL;
    // Need to capture the lambda instance here
    CL::set(f);
    // And finally call the cannot_change template function
    std::cout << cannot_change<Adapter<CL::adapter>>(20) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nTz9TE41W)

Unlike the comments above, you don't need to store the local `global` variable in a static variable (with all the trouble it makes).

Instead, this uses a lambda to capture the local variable. The lambda function instance is captured by a template `CaptureLambda` structure that's instantiated for this specific lambda.
This structure provides a static function with the signature matching the lambda's function signature.

Finally, the `Adapter` structure is instantiated with this static function's pointer and implements the interface **B** that `cannot_change` is expecting.

Please notice that:

1. Since each lambda are different type (even with the same signature), there can't be any conflict on the `CaptureLambda` static instance that must be set to the same lambda that is used to instantiate it. This means that there is no issue you could find with usual static variable
2. The `Adapter` being instantiated for this `CaptureLambda` specific instance, it can be completely optimized away by the compiler.
3. I've used a `std::function<>` in `CaptureLambda` because I was lazy. A better solution would be to actually copy/move/ref the lambda to avoid the overhead of `std::function`
4. If your lambda isn't capturing, don't bother using `CaptureLambda` and use `Adapter<decltype(f)>` directly in the `cannot_change` call, since a non capturing lambda is convertible to a function pointer directly.

Comment: One requirement is to use the magic function `cannot_change`, which can't change.

Comment: Please see my edit to call `cannot_change` with a capturing lambda.

Comment: @xryl669 what you did is actually just a global variable inside `CaptureLambda` class. You could just define global pointer pretty much the same way

Comment: Disagree. The static variable points to the lambda and not its captured value. In C++ you can't access the captured value of a lambda outside its scope, so you can't change it and mess with it unlike a global pointer to a variable that can be changed later on even after the capture.

Comment: @dmitry I think it's the best you can do with such interface. But since the `cannot_change` is a template, its definition must be visible so it should be very easy to modify it/copy it so it could accept a lambda directly and skip the whole static mess.